# How do I translate this logic?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Translate the following text into propositional logic:

"If Superman could and would want to prevent evil, would do so. If Superman could not prevent evil, he would be powerless; if he did not want to prevent evil, he would be evil. Superman does not prevent evil. If Superman exists, he is not powerless or evil.”

Chosenand then an interpretation and calculated the value under interpretation of the resulting sentence.

Comment: If...,then...; if...,then...; and so on.

Comment: 1) If Could Prevent and Want Prevent, then Do Prevent. 2) If not-CP, then Powerless. 3) If not-WP, then Evil. 4) not-DP. 5) If Superman Exists, then not-(Powerless or Evil). Thus, we assume that Superman Exists and derive (using DeMorgan): 6) not-Powerless and not-Evil. Form 6), with 2) and 3) we get 7) CP and 8) WP. With them, from 1) we derive 9) DoPrevent. Thus, we have a contradiction with 4). Conclusion: Superman does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

This is complicated since it uses counterfactuals and since you say “if Superman exists”. This makes me think you need to translate this into Quantified Free Modal Logic, as opposed to propositional logic. Of course, if you want to lose precision you can do it with just propositional logic, in a similar way that one would translate “All humans are mortal; Socrates is a human, therefore Socrates is mortal.”

Comment: IMO, your suggestion is too complicated for the introductory level of  the question above :-)